# Scheme function times called

Tags: function, scheme

If I call the following function 300 times, how many times does `expt` get called? I am inclined to believe that it is 300. Also, what are the actual values passed in each call? Are they -1 and n?

```
(define (infinite-series n )
    (if (= n 0)
        1
        (+ (* 4.0 (/ (expt -1 n) (+ 1 (* n 2)))
                  (infinite-series (- n 1 ))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recursive function, so the number of times it gets called depends on the input. Each recursion decrements `n` by `1`, until it reaches `0`, and `expt` is called once for each time this is called with non-zero input. So if you call `(infinite-series 10)`, `expt` will be called `10` times, and if you do that `300` times, `expt` will be called a total of `3000` times. If you call `infinite-recursion` 300 times with different inputs, the total number of calls to `expt` will depend on those inputs.

You're correct that the actual values passed to `expt` will be `-1` and `n`.